# Web scraping with pandas or beautifulsoup or selenium

Tags: pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and am presently experimenting with tensorflow and (py)torch. I want to apply these experiments to lotteries as many suggest that prediction is not possible. Please help me to scrape the webpage https://www.superenalotto.net/en/(+year in range(2023,2010) as I am not experienced in it.
Many thanks in advance.

Pandas, but the results were disorderly

Comment: Hi. This question is too broad. You're unlikely to get answers. But you will likely want to look into the requests module and BeautifulSoup to parse the results or maybe Python Selenium if the data is loaded with JavaScript. You could then pass that data to Pandas. But you will need to do some research and try for yourself and open a new question if you have issues

Comment: Hi this is my effort so far Loading libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from urllib.request import urlopen
from collections import Counter
import re
import csv 

Initialisation
pagenumber = 1
arawdata = []
brawdata = []
officialdata = {}

Accessing the web page
while pagenumber <= 1: # filtering through the pages.
counter = 0
url = urlopen('https://www.lotto.net/superenalotto/results'.format(pagenumber))
raw = url.read()
# print(raw)
url.close()  I downloaded the file, data needed only on line 170. Pls see next comment

Comment: L169 href="https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=lottodotnet" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="SuperEnalotto Results for Saturday 25 February 2023 available at" needed [Saturday 25 February 2023]. And then...data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="row-2">\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t<ul class="balls">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<li class="ball ball"><span>6</span><div></div></li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<li class="ball ball"><span>42</span><div></div></li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<li class=...etc. I hope anyone help. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that without selenium and even beautifulsoup, just requests and lxml. Code below show example for the year 2023

```
import requests, lxml.html

url = 'https://www.superenalotto.net/en/results/2023'
html = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get(url).text)
data = {key:[] for key in ['date','main','jolly','superstar']}
rows = html.xpath("//tbody/tr[not(@class)]")
for row in rows:
    data['date']  += [' '.join(row.xpath("./td[contains(@class,'date')]/text()"))]
    data['main']  += [row.xpath("./td[@class='ballCell'][1]//li/text()")]
    data['jolly'] += [row.xpath("./td[@class='ballCell'][2]//li/text()")[0]]
    data['superstar'] += [row.xpath("./td[@class='ballCell'][3]//li/text()")[0]]

import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much. sorry that did not show my effort in the first instance.regards.

Comment: @drjam If the question is solved you may consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking ✔ on the left.